# Group relations: Prove that $\forall u,v\in G$, $uv\sim vu$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $G$ be a group.

1. Prove that the relation $a\sim b$ if $b=gag^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$, is an equivalence relation on $G$.
2. Prove that $\forall u,v\in G$, $uv\sim vu$.

So I've proved (1). My confusion lies in the fact that they appear to be the same question. I'm sure I must be wrong, but my approach was to again show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. My proof is as follows:

*Proof.*

1. Suppose $u,v\in G$. Then $e(uv)e^{-1}=uv$. Therefore $uv\sim uv$ and $\sim$ is reflexive.
2. Suppose $uv\sim vu$ and that $u,v\in G$. Then $vu=g(uv)g^{-1}$ and 
   \begin{align}
       g^{-1}(vu)g&=g^{-1}(g(uv)g^{-1})g\\\
       &=(g^{-1}g)uv(g^{-1}g)\\\
       &=uv
   \end{align}
   Therefore, $uv\sim vu$ and $\sim$ is symmetric.
3. Suppose $uv\sim vu$ and $vu\sim xy$. Then, there exists $g,h\in G$ such that $vu=g(uv)g^{-1}$ and $xy=h(vu)h^{-1}$. Then,
   \begin{align}
       xy&=h(vu)h^{-1}\\\
   &=h(g(uv)g^{-1}\\\
   &=(hg)uv(hg)^{-1}\\\
   &=uv
   \end{align}
   Therefore $uv\sim xy$ and $\sim$ is transitive.

Thus, thus $uv\sim vu$ for all $u,v\in G$.

And this proof is almost the same as the proof I did for (1), so naturally I'm second guessing my answer for (2). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're assuming the conclusion.

Comment: @ChrisCuster I thought so when I was writing it, and maybe I need to review my relations proofs, but I thought for reflexive we prove that $uv\sim uv$, symmetry we prove that if $uv\sim vu$ then $vu\sim uv$ and then transitivity that if $uv\sim vu$ and $vu\sim xy$ then $uv\sim xy$.

Comment: You don't want to show that $uv\sim uv$ for reflexivity, but that $u\sim u$. Similarly, for symmetry and transitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part we need to show $uv\sim vu$ for any $u,v\in G$. So we need to find $ g \in G$ such that $ vu = g (uv)g^{-1}$ ... $g=u^{-1}$ will do.

Comment: Oh.. I see it. I suppose I struggle with knowing what I'm supposed to be doing. This was much simpler than I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need a $g\in G$ such that $guvg^{-1}=vu$.  But $g=v$ works: $vuvv^{-1}=vu$.